# Горизонтальный скролл

Tags: javascript

Можете показать или кинуть пример вот такого горизонтального скрола, а так же чтобы  он работал и от колесика мышки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отслеживаешь скролл когда мышка находится поверх этого блока и в зависимости от направления скролла изменяешь translate.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector('.main').addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
  var target = event.target;

  while (target != document.body) {
    if (target.classList.contains('main')) {
      e = window.event || e;
      var delta = e.deltaX || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;

      target.scrollLeft -= delta;
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    target = target.parentNode;
  }

});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.main div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  height: 80px;
}

.main div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: darkgray;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.main div:hover::after {
  display: block;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div>
    Поселения
  </div>
  <div>
    Сооружения
  </div>
  <div>
    Природа
  </div>
  <div>
    Традиции и <br> промыслы
  </div>
  <div>
    Даты<br> и события
  </div>
  <div>
    Персоны
  </div>
  <div>
    Гастрономия
  </div>
  <div>
    Образы
  </div>
  <div>
    ....
  </div>
  <div>
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как сделать если ширина не известная у main ?

Comment: @MaximLensky, а в чём разница известна ширина или нет? Убираем ширину у всех дивов и всё. Для наглядности можно увеличить padding влево и вправо

Comment: спасибо .......

Comment: А если будет и вертикальный скролл, то он тоже будет срабатывать.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko там надо сменить deltaY вместо deltaX, так ?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, почему? Не будет. Срабатывать будет только вертикальный скролл самой страницы

Comment: Будет будет. Попробуйте. @MaximLensky нет, надо отменять стандартное действие при скролле, а именно `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Просто e.preventDefault() тут не поможет... я попробовал. Надо подумать над устранением проблемы :)

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко Почему не поможет?)

Comment: Я только что попробовал, он не решил проблему

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko return false ?

Comment: Все проще. Надо событие прослушивания ставить не на `body` а на `.main`.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, гениально))) Спасибо, поправил

Comment: Теперь лучше работает! Ловите плюсик. @MaximLensky все было проще)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko да я тоже думал о main просто ещё глубже в дебри полез :))

Comment: То что нужно, но теперь этот скрол не работает на мобильных устройства.

Comment: @Js ученик, либо подключайте плагины что-то типа "smooth scroll", либо специально для мобильной версии добавить кнопки "взад-вперёд"

Comment: Тобишь так это нормально не реализуешь?